# When I must reward player for watching video in the core (libgdx)?

Tags: android, libgdx, admob-rewardedvideoad

I am making a game on LibGdx that has video ads. I implemented interface and it's methods. Everything works, video is shown.

AndroidLauncher:

```
public class MainAndroidLauncherAuthorization extends AndroidApplication implements 
AdsController, RewardedVideoAdListener, AdHandler {

private static final String TAG = "GoogleActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
private RewardedVideoAd rewardedVideoAd;
private boolean isRewardLoaded;
private boolean completed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    initialize(new STARTGame(this, this), config);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917");
    rewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    rewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}

public void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    isRewardLoaded=false;
    rewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new 
AdRequest.Builder().build());
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    isRewardLoaded =true;
}

@Override
public void showRewardedVideo() {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                rewardedVideoAd.show();
            } else {
                loadRewardedVideoAd();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean hasVideoReward(){
    return isRewardLoaded;
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
       }

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
    completed = true;
}

@Override
public boolean addCoins() {
    return completed;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    rewardedVideoAd.resume(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    rewardedVideoAd.pause(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    rewardedVideoAd.destroy(this);
}

@Override
public void coin_10() {
    Prefs prefs = new Prefs();
    prefs.plus_Coins_bank(10);
}
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface AdsController {
void showRewardedVideo();
void loadRewardedVideoAd();

boolean addCoins();

boolean hasVideoReward();
```

Core:

```
public class Win_01_18 extends Window implements AdsController, AdHandler {
private  Prefs prefs;

public Win_01_18(AdHandler sums, final AdsController adsController, final AssetMan assetMan) {
    super("", assetMan.get_skin_dialogs(), "dialog_window_main");

    *******

    Button btn_buy_10 = new Button(assetMan.get_skin_buttons_coins_video(), "btn_video_long");
    ***
    btn_buy_10.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

            adsController.showRewardedVideo();

            super.clicked(event, x, y);
        }
    });

@Override
public void showRewardedVideo() {

}

@Override
public void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
}

@Override
public boolean addCoins() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean hasVideoReward() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void coin_10() {
}
```

Everything works. There are 2 questions:
1 - How to check the *onRewardedVideoCompleted()* method from **core-class**?
2 - On what event should the coins be added for watching a video in the **core-class**?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently trying this myself. But what about changing the

```
void showRewardedVideoAd()
```

to a boolean

```
boolean showRewardedVideoAd()
```

And then in the onRewardedVideoCompleted() you return true and if it fails you return false.

Then in the core where you call the ad you put

```
boolean adFinished = False;
adFinished = adsController.showRewardedVideo();
if(adFinished){
    // give them the coins or whatever
} else {
    // the ad failed or the clicked it away early or something. Don't give them coins and go on
}
```